# Tiling shower walls how and where to start

Tags: tiling

I'm about to start tiling my shower walls I just don't know where to start or how, I've never tiled before my shower is 5ft in length 32 inches wide and 80 inches high I have chosen a 12 by 24 inch tile but got 10 by 16 inch tiles I got everything I need for the job just need advice for starting and laying the tiles

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is too broad for our Q&A format. Please take our tour to see how better to contribute here.

Answer (score 3):

If both corners are equally visible the best way is to start in the middle plumb on center. As you get to the corner measure and cut to fill. The leftover peice is the size of your starter for the next wall. Draw a new plumb line on the short wall according to off cut. This method does not always work out. If you end up with a tiny piece in the corner, offset your center line until visually appealing.

If your tile is 16 wide it would work out like this
[image]
Your short starter peice on the short wall would be about 5-1/2 inches

Starting at one corner is much easier but real professionals will normally start on center.

Comment: +1 for adjusting the starting point until "visually appealing".

Comment: That's exactly what I got, nice much respect

Answer (score 1):

Best place to start is on the bottom of the largest wall. Start in the corner that will be seen most. This will be your "pretty" corner. Finish that wall and then start at the bottom corner of the smaller walls and work up and out. You can save all your cutting till the end of each wall or cut as you go up. This also might depend on you laying pattern and how good you think you can slide them in. Some people measure and cut all at once before starting, some cut as they go, and some do all the wall row end cuts when finished with the wall. Your last 2 walls can be done at the same time. Make sure, if you precut, to include grout lines in your calculations.

Comment: Fine to start in a corner but you should check how close your grout lines will be to the other edges. You don't want to get to the other side or the top of the shower and realise you need a narrow sliver of tile to finish it. If that's going to happen, start with a half or 3/4 tile instead of a whole one. If there are any other features in the shower that will need tiling around you might want to check where those will end up in relation to the grout lines too.